# Custom gradle project with jar output

Tags: android, gradle

I want to have a gradle "project" that creates a jar using a custom task (doesn't use any of the gradle java plugins).  What is the proper way to construct the build.gradle so that I can depend on it in my android app's gradle project?

More Details:

Currently my jar file is being created in a cmake project that I call from gradle.
I want to have a proper build.gradle file that calls my cmake command then uses the resulting jar as the artifact.  Then I would like to be able to simply add "compile project(':mylib') from my android project's build.gradle.

Answer (score -1):

you can make a jar task like:

```
task myJar(type:Jar) {
    archiveName='my.jar'
    from sourceSets.main.output
    include 'foo/com/**/*', 'bar/com/**/*'
}
```

Comment: If im not mistaken, this example compiles some java files into a jar.  This isn't what I need.  The jar in my project is actually compiled in a cmake project that I call from gradle.

Comment: i don't know if gradle knows about cmake, so you might have to invoke it yourself like: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_execute_shell_command_source_or_dot_doestnt_work_with_exec - this should make the files you need.